# Casting List<bool> to List<object>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, covariance

Is there any shortcut or better way to typecast `List<bool>` to `List<object>`?

I know i can do that by looping and casting individual item but i want to know is this possible to cast entire list in one statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can do this with the [`Enumerable.Cast<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) method:

```
List<bool> bools= GetBoolList();
IList<Object> objects= bools.Cast<Object>().ToList();
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example for the same. I have never used like that.

Comment: was just doing it as you were asking :)

Comment: @Sam: OP wants the other way round, cast a bool to an object.

Comment: It's worth noting that this has the same effect as creating a new list and having a loop in which you case each item as you add it.  It hides the loop, but the code is still O(n) not O(1) the way it could be if you could just cast the list.

Answer (score 6):

The non-LINQ way to do this is with `List.ConvertAll`:

```
List<bool> b = new List<bool> { true, false, true };
List<object> o = b.ConvertAll(x => (object)x);
```

Since this method knows what size to make the new list, it is likely to be faster than the LINQ version for large lists.

Comment: Thanks Gabe! That's the easiest way.

Comment: `ConvertAll` creates a new `List<TResult>` whereas LINQ's `Cast` yields the casted items.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Yes, but the OP is looking for a `List<object>` not an `IEnumerable<object>`.

Comment: @Gabe: Correct, `ToList` would also create a copy. But i don't udnerstand your point that `ConvertAll` unlike `Cast...ToList()` knows the size. Both know the size since the source is a `List` not an `IEnumerable`(it is castable to `ICollection<T>`).

Comment: @TimSchmelter isn't the point that the Cast... just returns a yielded enumerable so the ToList() on the end *doesn't* know the size...

Comment: @SamHolder: It returns the same IEnumerable(actually the list) when the destination type is assignable from the  current type(what is the case since bool inherits object). `ToList`will try to cast the given `IEnumerable<T>` to `ICollection<T>` what is possible since it is already a list.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I suggest you run `new List<bool>().Cast<object>().GetType()`. What you're saying is only correct for reference types, of which `bool` is not one.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Never mind what I just said. `ICollection<T>` is not covariant like `IEnumerable<T>`, so it cannot cast `List<T>` to `ICollection<object>` for any `T` other than `object`. In this case there is no way for `ToList` to know the size of the source list.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<bool> list = new List<bool>{true,true,false,false,true};
List<Object> listObj1 = list.Select(i=> (Object)i).ToList();// First way
List<Object> listObj2 = list.Cast<Object>().ToList();// Second way 
List<Object> listObj3 = list.OfType<Object>().ToList();// Third way
```

Following is to test quickly in [linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

```
 list.Dump();
 listObj1.Dump();
 listObj2.Dump();
 listObj3.Dump();
```